# Cambiar el valor de un id de checkbox MVC4

Tags: c#, razor

Tengo un problema con los checkbox de mi vista,  y es que no consigo entender como puedo coger todos los valores que estan seleccionados y mandarlos al controlador para poder operar con ellos.

Tengo lo siguiente: Vista.

```
@model List<Model.ofertas_contactos>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Listado general de solicitudes";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">
</head>
@* Empieza la vista *@
<body style=" background-color:#353435">

    <h1 style="color:#fff; padding-top:30px" align="center">Listado General de Solicitudes Pendientes</h1>
    <br />
    <table align="center" class="table-striped, text-center, table-condensed" style="font-size:20px" cellpadding="20">
        @* Cabecera *@
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center" style="color:#e98300;font-family:'Trebuchet MS'">
                <th class="text-center" ; bgcolor="black"><input type="checkbox" name="chkAll" value="All" id="selecctall" /></th>
                <td class="text-center" ; bgcolor="black">Hora solicitud</td>
                <td class="text-center" ; bgcolor=" black">Capturar</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
               foreach (Filtro)
                {

                   <tr style="color:white ;font-family:'Trebuchet MS'">
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="sid" value="@usu.idContacto" class="checkbox1" /></td>
                        <td>@usu.fechaHora</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="~/home/capturar/@usu.idContacto" title="Capturar"></a></td>
                    </tr>

                }


        </tbody>
    </table>
    @*Boton*@
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="ruta/cambiarCampo" title="Cambiar Campo" style="margin-left:473px; margin-top:30px">Cambiar Campo</a>
</body>
```

Y en el HomeController tengo lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult cambiarCampo(int[] id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que lo que debes igualar con el parametro del controller es el `name` del tag en html

En tu caso el checkbox tiene el name="sid" por lo que el parametro deberia llevar ese mismo nombre

```
public ActionResult cambiarCampo(int[] sid)
{
    return View();
}
```

Lo que no veo en el codigo es que realices un POST al servidor para enviar estos datos, si solo usas el link estarias enviando un unico valor por GET en la url.

Deberias definir el codigo dentro de un

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("cambiarCampo")){

    //aqui defines html con los checkbox     

}
```

y en el action defienes el metodo que reciba los datos en el POST al realizar el submit

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult cambiarCampo(int[] sid)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, estaba muy perdido, ahora ya me va al ActionResult.